# First group cohomology and composition factors

Tags: representation-theory, modules, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $k$ be a field ($\text{char}(k)=p>0$).
Let $P(k)$ be the projective cover of $k$. Assume that for any nontrivial simple $kG$-module $M$ we have $H^1(G,M)=0$. Does it mean that all composition factors of $P(k)$ are trivial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. $H^1(G,M) = \operatorname{Ext}_{kG}^1(k,M)$ describes how many ways $M$ can be a submodule of $N$ with $N/M \cong k$. $P(k)$ can only have composition factors that are “connected” to $k$ by paths of nonzero $\operatorname{Ext}_{kG}^1$. We prove this by induction on the Loewy length, that is, by considering the semisimple modules $J^n P(k) / J^{n+1} P(k)$ and their extensions $J^{n-1} P(k) / J^{n+1} P(k)$ where $J$ is the Jacobson radical of $kG$.

**Lemma:** $P(k) / J^2 P(k)$ only has trivial composition factors.

*Proof:* Let $Q$ be a maximal submodule of $J P(k)$ setting $M=J P(k)/Q$ to be the simple quotient module. Consider the short exact sequence $0 \to M \to P(k)/Q \to k \to 0$. Assume by way of contradiction that $M$ is not the trivial (central/principal) module $k$. Since $\operatorname{Ext}_{kG}^1(k,M) = 0$, the sequence splits. However, $J P(k)/Q$ is superfluous in $P(k)/Q$, so never has a supplement, much less a complement. This contradiction shows $M=k$. $\square$

**Proposition:** $P(k)$ only has trivial composition factors.

*Proof:* Suppose $P(k)/J^n P(k)$ only has composition factors isomorphic to $k$, and let $R$ be a maximal submodule of $J^n P(k)$. Set $M=J^n P(k)/R$ to be the simple quotient, and assume by way of contradiction that $M$ is not the trivial (central/principal) module $k$. Consider $$0 \to M \to J^{n-1} P(k)/R \to J^{n-1} P(k)/ J^n P(k) \to 0$$ and notice $J^{n-1} P(k)/ J^n P(k) \cong k^m$ for some positive integer $m$. Hence $$\operatorname{Ext}_{kG}^1(J^{n-1} P(k)/ J^n P(k),M) = \operatorname{Ext}_{kG}^1(k^m, M) = \operatorname{Ext}_{kG}^1(k,M)^m = 0^m = 0$$ so the sequence splits. However, $M = J^n P(k) / R = J ( J^{n-1} P(k)/R )$ is superfluous, so not a direct summand. This contradiction shows that in fact $M$ must be isomorphic to $k$. Since $J^n P(k) / J^{n+1} P(k)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of such $M$, the induction proceeds to show that $J^n P(k) / J^{n+1} P(k)$ and hence $P(k) / J^{n+1} P(k)$ only has trivial composition factors. Since $P(k)$ has finite Loewy length, $P(k)$ itself only has trivial composition factors. $\square$

The more intuitive method view $P(k)$ made up of layers. The top layer is a single copy of $k$, and the second layer is proven in the lemma to only have copies of $k$ again. What can happen in the third layer? Well the third layer of $P(k)$ is actually the second layer of $J (k)$ and since $J P(k)$ is a homomorphic image of $P(k)^m$, its second layer also only has copies of $k$. Thinking of this in terms of the original copy of $P(k)$, we see the third layer of $P(k)$ also only has trivial composition factors. In other words the $n$th layer of $P(k)$ is the second layer of $J^{n-2} P(k)$, and if $J^{n-2} P(k)$ only has trivial top composition factors, then it is a homomorphic image of $P(k)^m$, etc.

This kind of thing is uncommon in finite groups. I believe this is only the case when the principal block contains only one simple module. I think this is the case when $G/O_{p'}(G)$ is a $p$-group, but I don't have my references around to double check.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the first paragraph, but not the second one. I know that the projective cover of a direct sum of copies of $k$ is a direct sum of copies of $P(k)$, but I don't understand what your argument is. Can you please elaborate on the second paragraph?

Comment: @user3533 I added a more formal proof. I also made the intuitive proof a little clearer (you have to build a building and can only stack k on top of k. What kind of things get stacked? Only k!). I don't have my references handy, but I believe finite groups satisfying your hypothesis are classified and are nearly p-groups .

Comment: That looks great. I understand the formal proof, except for the part in the proof of the proposition where you say that $J^nP(k)/J^{n+1}P(k)$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of such $M$. Why is that true? (I think you're using this fact in the proof of the Lemma as well).

Comment: Also, does the inductive proof work if we change the Lemma to the simpler claim that $P(k)/JP(k)$ is a direct sum of copies (actually, just one copy) of $k$. Does the inductive proof really has to "start from 2"?

Comment: I think I can answer my first question: $J^nP(k)/J^{n+1}P(k)$ is semisimple and therefore any of its factors may appear as the top factor of $J^nP(k)$ and you have shown that any such top factor is isomorphic to $k$. Is that it?

Comment: @user3533: yes, exactly. The intersection of all the "R" is $J^{n+1} P(k)$. -- I think one can ignore the lemma in the final draft. In an earlier draft, it was used explicitly, but I think in this one, not only are the proofs similar, the lemma has been subsumed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have really learned a lot from your answers here to my and others' questions.

Comment: No problem. I'll see if I can find the reference for the classification of such groups, as I think you asked that explicitly  a while back.

Comment: I think I'm going to classify them using your answer here :) A reference would get great too though.